# Export and Import in Node.js 4.2.1

Tags: javascript, node.js

I have two files.

other.js

```
export var test = 12;
export var test2 = 'testing';
```

main.js

```
import other from "other.js";
console.log(other);
```

I write `node main.js`. I expect this:

```
{
    test: 12,
    test2: 'testing'
}
```

But I get an error:

```
(function (exports, require, module, __filename, __dirname) { import oth from "other.js";
                                                              ^^^^^^

SyntaxError: Unexpected reserved word
```

Node.js version 4.2.1. What's wrong?

Comment: You're sure you don't want to `require` instead, or are you playing with ES2015

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Node doesn't support `import`, `export` (yet? who knows). See https://nodejs.org/en/docs/es6/ for a list of support features.

You either need to keep using CommonJS modules or use a transpiler such as [Babel](https://babeljs.io/).

Comment: Don't we have a dupe for this already?

Comment: I thought so but couldn't find it. If you find it, let me know :)

Comment: I guess I just did (keywords: `node module support [es6]`)

Answer (score 1):

You need to import everything and assign them an alias...

But you cannot do that without a Transpiler, 
***es6 modules*** aren't available...

```js
import * as other from './other.js';

console.log(other);
```